# Rails - Multiple file upload form with additional input for each file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I'm working on an app at work where users can upload files to a project. Right now I'm using paperclip, and all of the file info (name, file type, etc.) is recorded properly.

The problem I'm having is that the users need to assign a category to each file.

What is the best approach to implement something like this? I'm on my phone right now, but I'll attach any pertinent code when I get to work, if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Here's more info on the setup.
I need to assign the file type (which is more like a category than a file type. I didn't name the fields!) So all of the info is in a single table. Although `accepts_nested_attributes` will definitely come in handy down the road!

Here's the table structure. All of the `document_` fields are set by paperclip. The only one that needs user input is the `file_type` field.

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| document_file_name    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| document_content_type | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| document_file_size    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| document_updated_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| project_id            | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id               | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| file_type             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at            | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at            | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: not sure if i understand the problem, but for multiple file upload at once i suggest you checkout `accepts nested attributes for` in ActiveRecord

Answer (score 0):

According to Zippie, you can check [Nested Model form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1). I'm also not sure if it works for files.  You can get ideas from this tutorials.

Comment: it does work for files as far as i know, don't see a reason why it wouldn't

Comment: @Zippie, Thanks for your suggestion. It cleared my confusion.